# 74HC93 glitching problem

Tags: power-supply, 7segmentdisplay

Solved: Apparently, on the 555, you need to connect pin #4 to VCC to avoid false triggering. (Thanks [ericgibbs](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/members/ericgibbs.73660/))

I have a circuit that utilizes a 74HC93 4-bit counter. The clock signal for this counter originates from a 555 timer. The output of the counter (specifically Q0 & Q1) is connected to various logic gates, ultimately controlling the letters on three 7-segment displays.

Initially, the circuit functioned flawlessly when powered by a brand-new 9-volt battery with a voltage regulator. However, it now has frequent glitches. sometimes the displays get stuck on the first set of letters, other times they operate normally, and sometimes they switch super fast.

I connected the circuit to a 5V power bank, which resulted in a 50% less glitches.
However, powering the circuit directly with a 5V wall adapter almost eliminated the problem, with glitches occurring only once in like 100 operations.

I would appreciate if someone explain why was this happening, and how to stop it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much current your device draws? If the current is larger to what the battery can provide, or if the battery runs out quickly due to load, it can't give out enough to what 7805 required at input. Have you measured any voltages when it glitches?

Comment: Decoupling capacitors are missing. How does the Vcc pin look on each IC on your oscilloscope?

Comment: @Justme I don't have a way to measure. Also I already ditched the 7805 and the problem still persists.

Comment: @winny Thanks. How many capacitors would I need? And where to place them.
Also, I don't have an oscilloscope :(

Comment: @Michael Not even a multimeter? Then you can't even know if the battery is dead and it does not work because of that.

Comment: Check the input and output caps requirements on your regulator as per StarCat's answer below. On top of that start with 100 nF as close to the Vcc and GND pin of every IC. If you pursue a career in EE or even home tinkerer, you will need an oscilloscope. Cheapest USB based one is good enough for these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The schematics are not very easy to read, but it looks like your power supply is not decoupled, which will produce small drops (transients) in the supply voltage when logic gates are switching. On a breadboard this can easily cause glitches.

As a general rule of thumb, it is recommended to add decoupling capacitors of around 0.1-0.33 μF to the input and the output of the 7805 regulator and a 100 nF capacitor near the supplies of each IC.

From the [LM7805 / LM340 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've decided to ditch the regulator and use the power bank. Should I connect the 0.1uF capacitor between the GND and VCC? Also, regarding the 100nF capacitor near the supply, does this mean I should place one leg in the VCC and the other in the GND of all ICs?

Comment: A 100 nF capacitor near the supply of each IC, except the 555, which needs more capacitance due to its tendency for shoot-through. The 555 should have at least 1 μF, maybe even more.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of inductance in the power supply wiring, inductance which limits the rate at which current in those wires can change. Digital (and some analogue) ICs have extremely rapid voltage transitions at their outputs, requiring very sudden changes in power supply current. Without any measures to mitigate inductance, each transition evokes a very sudden increase in current demand, which the wiring and the power supply would be unable to satisfy. The result is a short but significant dip in power supply voltage whenever any output flips state.

These "dips" can easily be large enough to lower the power supply voltage near the IC that caused it, and other nearby devices, below the minimum voltage needed to operate properly.

This can be mitigated by using power supply decoupling capacitors installed any place where current demand can suddenly spike. This would include ICs with fast changing outputs, or ICs or H-bridges driving medium-to-heavy loads such as LEDs and motors. Most things, really. The capacitors act as short-term energy reservoirs, able to accommodate sudden spikes in current demand from the power supply, until the real power supply can "catch up". Higher current, faster devices (and their loads) should be accompanied by greater bypass capacitance.

They have major benefits:

1. The sudden short voltage dips near each IC will be greatly diminished, for a more steady supply voltage to the IC.
2. Other systems powered from the same supply, which would also suffer from supply voltage fluctuations, are also protected.

These capacitors would be ceramic, 10nF (at least), connected directly across the power supply lines (typically Vcc and ground), one for each and every IC. Connect them as physically close to the power supply pins of those ICs as possible. Do this for both the 555 and 74HC devices.

As user StarCat pointed out, you are also missing the two capacitors on either side of the 7805 regulator. The input-side capacitor is just for supply bypass, as described above. The output-side capacitor serves that purpose too, but it also stabilises the regulator itself, keeping it from oscillating or ringing. Some regulators would oscillate without it. This particular model, the 7805, might experience some overshoot and ringing without the output capacitor in place. See the [7805 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf) for appropriate capacitor values.

None of the capacitors I have described here are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, on the 555, you need to connect pin #4 to VCC to avoid false triggering.
(Thanks [ericgibbs.73660](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/members/ericgibbs.73660/))
[image]

Comment: That's part of your issue. The bigger part of the issue is the lack of decoupling capacitors.